How to change Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RadioButtonSource start buttonTimeTable value in OMPython for prebuilt Model?
I want to simulate Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks model with start, stop, shut control logic.
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RadioButtonSource start(
      reset={stop.on,shut.on},
      buttonTimeTable={20,280})

If I want to change start time {50,350}, how to change in OmPython editor?
My code:
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
omc.sendExpression("simulate(Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks, outputFormat=\"csv\")")`

I tried like this:
omc.sendExpression("setElementModifierValue(Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks,start.buttonTimeTable,{50,350})")


omc.sendExpression("buildModel(Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks,
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RadioButtonSource.start.buttonTimeTable={50,350})")

but nothing works

You can try something like this:
model=ModelicaSystem(modelName = "Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks")
...................
model.setSimulationOptions(["startTime=50.0","stopTime=400.0"])
......................

I just tried your model, here is result:

